# Plotly contour plot colour scale granularity not matching custom colorscale

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a contour plot with colours from black at a value of -1 to light grey at 0 to red at a value of 1.

I created a custom colorscale that looks like this, where I specified colours for each increment of 0.1 (20 increments from -1 to 1)

```
[ # Black -> Light grey
        [0, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'],[0.05, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'],
        [0.05, 'rgb(20, 20, 20)'],[0.1, 'rgb(20, 20, 20)'],
        [0.1, 'rgb(40, 40, 40)'],[0.15, 'rgb(40, 40, 40)'],
        [0.15, 'rgb(60, 60, 60)'],[0.2, 'rgb(60, 60, 60)'],
        ...
        [0.4, 'rgb(160, 160, 160)'],[0.45, 'rgb(160, 160, 160)'],
        [0.45, 'rgb(180, 180, 180)'],[0.5, 'rgb(180, 180, 180)'],
         # Ligt Grey -> Red
        [0.5, 'rgb(187, 162, 162)'],[0.55, 'rgb(187, 162, 162)'],
        [0.55, 'rgb(194, 144, 144)'],[0.6, 'rgb(194, 144, 144)'],
        [0.6, 'rgb(201, 126, 126)'],[0.65, 'rgb(201, 126, 126)'],
        ...
        [0.9, 'rgb(243, 18, 18)'],[0.95, 'rgb(243, 18, 18)'],
        [0.95, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'],[1, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)']]
```

However, when I output the plot, my colorscale has increments of 0.2 and so it seems that not all of the colours I specified are shown.
Here is what I get

[image]

This is part of the code to display plot, I am not sure what would be needed to have more information.

```
data = [go.Contour(z=df.values.tolist(),x=list(df.columns),y=list(df.index),colorscale = colScale,zmin=-1,zmax=1)]
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig,contours= contour,filename='contPlot'+column)
```

I am looking for a way to have more colors displayed. Is there a way to display how many "splits" you want in the colour scale where it will interpolate between colours that have been specified ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are parameters related to the [contours](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#contour-contours) attribute:

```
go.Contour(
    z=df.values.tolist(),
    x=list(df.columns),
    y=list(df.index),
    colorscale=colScale,
    contours=dict(
        size=0.1,
        start=-1,
        end=1
    )
)
```

also you don't need to graduate the color scale yourself, you should only use the base colors:

```
[
  [0, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'],[0.5, 'rgb(187, 162, 162)'],
  [0.5, 'rgb(187, 162, 162)'],[1, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)']
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the second part of your answer, it helped me get better colourscale, however, the size part does not work and does not change the splits in the colourscale. Any idea why this is ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to swap the `zmin` and `zmax` for `start` and `end` in `contours`. I edited the answer, now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally used ncontours to change the number of colour in the colour scale.

```
data = go.Contour(
    z=df.values.tolist(),
    x=list(df.columns),
    y=list(df.index),
    colorscale = colScale,
    zmin=-1,
    zmax=1,
    ncontours=25)
```

Comment: Be careful with `ncontours`, from the docs: "Sets the maximum number of contour levels. The actual number of contours will be chosen automatically to be less than or equal to the value of `ncontours`." meaning if you don't have enough data that number could be smaller.